# With function to connect php

Tags: php, function, connection, undefined

it works... (without the function part) but when I try to use the function on another file I get errors:

```
<?php
    function conectar() {
        $s = "localhost";
        $u = "root";
        $p = "";
        $bd = "bd_banco_cesde";

        //$conexion = new msqli($s, $u, $p, $bd);
        //$conexion = @new msqli($s, $u, $p, $bd);
        $conexion = mysqli_connect($s, $u, $p, $bd);
        if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
            echo "No conectado";
        } else {
            echo "Conectado... uf";
        }
    }
    include('php_conectado.php');
    $con = conectar();
    echo "$con";
?>
```

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7yV9.png)

Comment: In `conectar()` use `return` instead of `echo`

Answer (score 0):

Your function need some changes:

1. echo is not proper solution use die:
2. return connection because you need to use from that in the next codes.
3. print_r($con); connection to see its resault

   ```
       $conexion=mysqli_connect($s,$u,$p,$bd);

       if($conexion->connect_errno)
       {
           die("No conectado");
       }
       else
       {
           return $conexion;
       }
       return false;
   }
   //
   include(php_conectado.php);
   $con=conectar();
   print_r($con);
   ```

Also you can use return false; instead of die("No conectado");, and in this case when  $con is false there is no connection

Also you need to have $conexion for execution next queries and without that it is not possible to run query in this connection

Comment: I would say that `die` is not a 'proper' solution.

Comment: Also you can use return false; instead of die("No conectado");, and in this case when $con is false there is no connection

check my last sentence please

Comment: At the top of your post you suggest that using `die` is the way to do it.  Also the `return false;` at the end of the function serves no purpose as it should never get there.

Comment: you can use die because code should not continue if there is not proper connection, all CMS systems die or exit application where is not any connection
Also i put my last sentence to say that it is possible to continue according to your logic.

Comment: Also you need to have $conexion for execution next queries and without that it is not possible to run query in this connection. with solution that i sent $con will be  $conexion

Comment: It seems to work, But I just passed the two files on a file, renamed one as idenx and I get this errors: Notice: Use of undefined constant php_conectado - assumed 'php_conectado' in C:\xampp\htdocs\banco_cesde\index.php on line 2

Notice: Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php' in C:\xampp\htdocs\banco_cesde\index.php on line 2

Warning: include(php_conectadophp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\banco_cesde\index.php on line 2